# How do you select an image at an index using DAMP in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I'm having trouble using DAMP with umbraco 6.

I have a field 'backgroundImages' that uses the DAMP data type and I'm trying to get the first image in the collection but I've no idea how to do it using the new API.

There's plenty of documentation for using DAMP with older versions of Umbraco but nothing for v6? Can anyone explain how I can get the collection of images I've picked for a node, and then pull out the first one using the new API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var nodeValue = node.GetProperty("image").Value.ToString()
var dynamicXml = new umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicXml(nodeValue);
var croppedUrl = DigibizAdvancedMediaPicker.DAMP_Helper.
                                GetImageCropperUrl(dynamicXml, "Thumbnail");
```